# hadoop always use my installation path to expand classpath on remote node and then load jar failed

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I'm a Hadoop&Hbase newbie. I've already run the WordCount example successfully. Now I modify the Mapper and try to use Hbase row as input data, so I need to import some HBase classes.

After I rebuild WordCount.jar and run:

```
$ hadoop jar ./out/artifacts/WordCount_jar/WordCount.jar WordCount
```

I got error like:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration
    at WordCount.main(WordCount.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

So I copy all hbase library to a folder and set HADOOP_CLASSPATH:

```
$ export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/home/kayuuzu/jar/*
$ hadoop fs -put /home/kayuuzu/jar/* /home/kayuuzu/jar/
$ hadoop jar ./out/artifacts/WordCount_jar/WordCount.jar WordCount
```

Now it found hbase classes but print error like:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://mycluster/ldata/bin/hadoop-2.3.0-cdh5.0.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce2/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.3.0-cdh5.0.1.jar
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1128)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:288)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:224)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestamps(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestampsAndCacheVisibilities(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1292)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1292)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1313)
    at WordCount.main(WordCount.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

hadoop classpath:

```
$ hadoop classpath:
/home/kayuzu/jar/*:/ldata/bin/hadoop-2.3.0-cdh5.0.1/etc/hadoop:/ldata/bin/hadoop-2.3.0-cdh5.0.1/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/ldata/bin/hadoop-2.3.0-cdh5.0.1/share/hadoop/common/*:/ldata/bin/hadoop-2.3.0-cdh5.0.1/share/hadoop/hdfs:/ldata/bin/hadoop-2.3.0-cdh5.0.1/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/ldata/bin/hadoop-2.3.0-cdh5.0.1/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/ldata/bin/hadoop-2.3.0-cdh5.0.1/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/ldata/bin/hadoop-2.3.0-cdh5.0.1/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/ldata/bin/hadoop-2.3.0-cdh5.0.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/ldata/bin/hadoop-2.3.0-cdh5.0.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*
```

It seems strangely using "ldata/bin/hadoop-2.3.0-cdh5.0.1"(my hadoop installation path) to expand classpath and tring to load jar from hdfs filesytem just like from local.

If I move hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.3.0-cdh5.0.1.jar to /home/kayuuzu/jar/ and upload it to hdfs://home/kayuuzu/jar/, this error will dismiss and then fail to load other class. It seems hadoop try to load class from hdfs using the same path on my local machine.

I guess it will work if I move all hadoop library file to one directory and upload it to hdfs keeping same path, but it will destroy my local hadoop installation and there is so many jar file.

Have I misunderstood something? How to specify library path of remote mapreduce?